# Access children of a custom element shadow dom

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, polymer, shadow-dom

I have a custom element using [mr. Ruyadornos simple-slider element.](https://github.com/ruyadorno/polymer-simple-slider)

(I am working on chrome)

won-thumbnail.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="SimpleSlider/simple-slider.html">

<polymer-element name="won-thumbnail" noscript>
    <template>
        <simple-slider style="width:200px; height: 100px;">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/612/613" />
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/612/614" />
        </simple-slider>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

When I place the simple-slider element directly into index.html, everything works well and I see 2 pictures of beautiful kittens sliding perfectly.

When I place the element into a custom element - as above - the slider does not work at all.

I dug a bit into the code of the slider and localized the problem:

```
console.log( this.containerElem ); // -> prints the simple-slider element correctly
console.log( this.containerElem.children ); // -> prints an array containing both images as expected
console.log( this.containerElem.children.length ); // -> prints 0 ???SOS???
console.log( JSON.stringify( this.containerElem.children ) ); // -> prints { "length": 0 }
```

Would anyone like to explain this behavior, please? :)

**EDIT**

I compared the output of `console.log( this.containerElem.children );` for the slider being directly in the index.html and then as a part of the custom element. In the index.html it is a circular structure, while in the other one it seems to be a standard array.

**Output from simple-slider element being called directly in index.html**
[image]

**Output from simple-slider while it resides in the custom element called in index.html**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are importing `SimpleSlider/simple-slider.html`, you should import `../bower_components/polymer-simple-slider/src/simple-slider.html`

I have created example project where it's working:

https://github.com/mkubenka/polymer-simple-slider-example